# Opening a DMG file and switching to it automatically

Tags: finder, dmg

When I click on a DMG file, finder opens and mounts it. Then I have to search for the new "disk" and select it.

Is there a way to open a DMG file and make finder select and show it automatically?

I don't want to create a DMG that does this. I want this behavior to be de default one for any DMG I download from the web.

Comment: Strange, automatically opening and switching to the mounted DMG window has been the default behaviour for me for as long as I can remember.... not even sure how I would stop it doing that. (I'm still running Mojave, though, maybe that's changed in newer versions?)

Comment: I can't remember anytime it worked automatically like that for me. It is very annoying.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you open Finder, right-click on a DMG, Open With...  is DiskImageMounter there and shown as the default, or has something else possibly overwritten that?

Comment: Having to search for it implies you don't have your disks showing on the desktop. They don't always open a window, but they always mount to the same spot on the desktop, just below any already-mounted disks.

Comment: @Tetsujin AHAAAAAAAAAAA!!!! That's it. I enabled "show external disks on desktop" and now the DMG opens automatically! BRILLIANT. Please make your comment an answer, so I can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all .dmg files open immediately to show their content in Finder [I think it depends entirely on whether they were open or not at creation/last Save], so if they don't, you need to have your Finder prefs set to show External disks. This will then show them to the right side of your desktop, below existing mounted partitions.

[image]

That way, if they don't auto-show, you can at least simply double-click them to open.